# Pi Pico SPI Interrupt only fires once

Tags: spi

I have set an interrupt for spi0 which fires only once.

Here is my entire code:

```
int main()

    spi_init(spi0, 1000 * 1000);
    spi_set_slave(spi0, true);
    gpio_set_function(PICO_DEFAULT_SPI_RX_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);
    gpio_set_function(PICO_DEFAULT_SPI_SCK_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);
    gpio_set_function(PICO_DEFAULT_SPI_TX_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);
    irq_set_enabled(SPI0_IRQ, true);
    
    irq_set_exclusive_handler(SPI0_IRQ, &recvSPI);

    spi0_hw->imsc = SPI_SSPIMSC_RTIM_BITS | SPI_SSPIMSC_RORIM_BITS | SPI_SSPIMSC_RXIM_BITS;

    
    // Wait forever
    
    while (1)
    {
    }
}
// interrupt routine
void recvSPI(void)
{
    ui8 = spi0_hw->dr;
    spi0_hw->icr = 3;
    gpio_put(25, pin^=1);
}
```

I send the SPI one character. It receives it correctly.

That's it. I have to restart the program to get another one.

in the callback, spi0_hw is

[image]

If anyone could offer even a clue I would be most grateful!

Comment: I've answered this myself. The Pi Pico doesn't work as an SPI slave without CS being connected and toggled between receives.

Comment: To make it helpful for others pls add this as a proper answer (if possible with a reference)  and accept the answer

Comment: I'd love to but I can't see how!

Comment: You should be able to add the solution below in the 'your answer' box

Answer (score 0):

The Pi Pico SPI module does not function without a connected and valid CS line. I can't use that because it is automatic and I want variable inputs.

I've decided to use PIO instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for PIO. It takes in a number of bits (currently 8, set by the SET x, 7 line in the state machine. Set that to bits-1.) It waits for CS to go low, then reads the bits. It could be improved by checking for CS to go high before all 8 bits have been received, later. When it receives the whole character it sets IRQ 1 and waits for the next character (autonomously) while the rest of the code deals with it.

Pins are data, clock, CS.

```
.program clocked_input

; Sample bits using an external clock, and push groups of bits into the RX FIFO.
; - IN pin 0 is the data pin
; - IN pin 1 is the clock pin
; - IN pin 2 is the CS pin
; - Autopush is enabled, threshold 8
;
; This program samples data with each rising clock edge (like mode 0 or mode 3
; SPI). The data is actually sampled one system clock cycle after the rising
; edge is observed, so a clock ratio of at least input_clk < clk_sys / 6 is
; recommended for good sampling alignment.
; wait for CS to go low
flush:
    wait 1 pin 2    ; wait for cs to go high
    wait 0 pin 2    ; wait for cs to go low
    set x, 7        ; set x scratch to 7
    mov isr, null   ; reset ISR (Shift reg)
again:
    wait 0 pin 1    ; wait for clock to go low
    wait 1 pin 1    ; wait for clock to go high
    in pins, 1      ; move single bit from pin (Rx Data) to Shift reg
    jmp x--, again  ; if x is not 0, decrement x and do next single bit
    push            ; but if it is, push ISR to FIFO
    irq wait 1      ; set IRQ and wait for it to clear
    jmp flush       ; restart from top
% c-sdk {
static inline void clocked_input_program_init(PIO pio, uint sm, uint offset, uint pin) {
    pio_sm_config c = clocked_input_program_get_default_config(offset);
    sm_config_set_clkdiv(&c, 1.0F);
    // Set the IN base pin to the provided `pin` parameter. This is the data
    // pin, and the next-numbered GPIO is used as the clock pin.
    sm_config_set_in_pins(&c, pin);
    // Set the pin directions to input at the PIO
    pio_sm_set_consecutive_pindirs(pio, sm, pin, 3, false);
    // Connect these GPIOs to this PIO block
    pio_gpio_init(pio, pin);
    pio_gpio_init(pio, pin + 1);
    pio_gpio_init(pio, pin + 2);
    // Shifting to left matches the customary MSB-first ordering of SPI.
    sm_config_set_in_shift(
        &c,
        false, // Shift-to-right = false (i.e. shift to left)
        false,  // Autopush enabled
        0      // Autopush threshold unused
    );

    // We only receive, so disable the TX FIFO to make the RX FIFO deeper.
    // sm_config_set_fifo_join(&c, PIO_FIFO_JOIN_RX);
    // Load our configuration, and start the program from the beginning
    pio_sm_init(pio, sm, offset, &c);
    pio_sm_set_enabled(pio, sm, true);
}
%}
```